# SPO - Hosted-Add-in Client picker and question for init.js library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, clientpeoplepicker, sp.js, clients.svc

I want to know:

- 1)
  Where i use **init.js** from ../_layouts/15/ (provider folder), and i sends 3 batches to server, fiddler show me 6 requests.. where i comment init.js library i really send 3 requests and  **SP.SOD.executeFunc** doesnt work without init.js...
  [image]

---

- 2) ***RESOLVED*** I need to use client picker in my app with this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx), can you tell me a better way to do it..

**This is my all libraries:**

```
    <!-- Required references to use Client Piker -->
    <script src="../_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../_layouts/15/clientforms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../_layouts/15/autofill.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--Мy custom code for Client Piker-->
    <script src="../Scripts/CustomClientPiker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Code in **CustomClientPiker** is code behind from msdn tutorial..

And i have this errors...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem..
Solution is add this js libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/1033/initstrings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/1033/strings.js"></script>
```

i want to know, how init.js sends more requests ?